# Choosing between 2 google map routes

Tags: usa, routes

I need to travel in my car from Milwaukee to Redmond and I see on Google maps that there are 3 options. Notice that routes #1 and #2 have almost the same distance.

[image]

I am wondering as different highways have different speed limits in the U.S., I am wondering which one has a higher speed limit so I can potentially get to the destination faster or maybe which one is going to be busier. And also which one is better for sightseeing as it's going to be a long drive. Or maybe if there is a third route. I appreciate any help.

[Reference](https://goo.gl/maps/R99n4Pe3xThBF9hx6)

Comment: They're all US Interstate Highways, so the road conditions will be similar and — construction aside — can be expected to be good. The most striking issue will be weather: if it's winter, the more northerly your route the greater chance of having winter weather affect your drive. OTOH driving through winter landscapes if it's not stormy will be very pretty. Your call!

Comment: The I-94 leg goes through Minneapolis, which can be quite busy and slow. This is pretty much the only major city on either route. Actual traffic will, of course, depend on what time you hit that area. From Billings onward they are both the same, so decide if you want to see North Dakota or South Dakota.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both routes almost have the same distance and the same predicted travel time. There will be little difference in overall drive time unless something unexpected happens on one of the routes.

Google factors in typical traffic density, speed limits, major construction,  average speed, etc.

> And also which one is better for sightseeing as it's going to be a long drive

That depends on what you define as sightseeing and what you personally find interesting. The main difference is that you can take the I94 through North Dakota or stay on I90 all they way and go through South Dakota.

You can put both routes into a trip planning site like roadtrippers.com (no advertisement intended). These sites will display "interesting stuff along the route" which includes sights to see, things to do, parks, food, gas, etc and you can  see what might tickle your fancy.

So if your life's dream has always been see the "World's Largest Buffalo Monument" take I94. However if your true ambition is to visit the "South Dakota Air and Space Museum", stay on I90.

Answer (score 2):

Google Maps takes into account traffic when the data is available. Of course when planning a trip ahead of time, conditions may not be as anticipated. You can set a day and time in the near-future but those are less reliable. If you want to know the best route, check the day you are leaving but for such a long trip, it means that you may not be able to know where exactly will be a good point to stop.

As you can see from your screenshot, Google shows you the distance and estimated time. This makes it easy to calculate the average speed which is more useful than the maximum speed since that is not always possible due to traffic. Even if you manage to go over the limit at times, it won't make as much difference compared to how much sleep to you take, how long you stop for meals, etc.

For the quickest travel time, follow Google Maps *Live* which requires a data connection. This allows Google to change the route while your trip is already in progress since traffic conditions will certainly change during that 29+ hour trip. Accidents and road closures allow the drive to adapt dynamically and so the final path may be *none of the above*.

If you want to plan ahead, reserve a night of hotel in the middle, choose restaurants to stop too, pick one route and plan to follow it with only minor detours. There is some overlap with the two shorter routes and time does not vary that much that it won't be much loss if it turns out the other one had better traffic the day of your trip.

Comment: "A" night? Probably at least 2 here, most likely 3.

Comment: While you could definitely make the trip in two long driving days, with only one night in a hotel, it would not allow for sightseeing of any kind.

Comment: At my age now, probably 3! When we were kids, my father did a 33h drive without sleeping. Us kids were in our sleeping bags in the back of the car most of the time. He's done in a few times in a single shot but when we were you adults, he split the trip in two. It was something we did every few years